# Split date range into new records for each month in Snowflake View

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, with-clause

```
Input                   
ID  StartDate   EndDate         
ABC 12/14/2020  1/14/2021           
XYZ 12/13/2020  12/23/2021          
DEF 12/3/2020   2/3/2021            
                    
Output                  
ID  StartDate   EndDate     YEAR    MONTH   No. Of Days
ABC 12/14/2020  12/31/2020  2020    12      18
ABC 1/1/2021    1/14/2021   2021    1       14
XYZ 12/13/2020  12/23/2020  2020    12      11
DEF 12/3/2020   12/31/2020  2020    12      29
DEF 1/1/2021    1/31/2021   2021    1       31
DEF 2/1/2021    2/3/2021    2021    2       3
```

Input and output samples are given above. Each record has to split by each month across the given date range.

Comment: It looks as if you want to split by the end of the year. Is that correct? Or do you want to split by end of month? What if it spans 3+ years. Should it be split into multiple years/rows (or months if that's the split)?

Comment: Each record need to split by month. if it is across 3+ years , it has to split by each month which would be 36+ months/rows

Comment: looks like you need to create a procedure that loops MONTHS_BETWEEN times and use if/else conditions to check if you hit the last month and functions DATEDIFF and LAST_DAY to calculate number of days.  Here are the time functions: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html

Comment: Your expected output does not seems to confirm with 'each record has to split by each month across the given date range", can you re-check it.

Comment: Pankaj, Output  looks fine as expected. Could you please point out where it is looking wrong

Comment: Why there is only 1 record for XYZ and 3 for DEF, if they needs to be split across month? For XYZ the range looks like almost a year.

Comment: Thanks! for the catch Pankaj. I have corrected it. Could you please assist now ?

Comment: I have added an answer, hope it meets your use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea here is to generate data-set with all dates filled in between start-date and end-date.
Used `table(split_to_table(repeat(',',TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, sdate,edate)-1),','))`, for same.
Once we have all dates, just select the relevant dates.

```
with data_cte (id,sdate,edate) as (
select * from values
('ABC','2020-12-14'::date,'2021-01-14'::date),
('XYZ','2020-12-13'::date,'2020-12-23'::date),
('DEF','2020-12-03'::date,'2021-02-03'::date)
), cte_2 as
(
select d.*,
case when sdate = edate then edate
else 
dateadd(day, index, sdate) 
end next_date,
last_day(next_date) ldate,
case when month(sdate) = month(next_date) 
AND year(sdate) = year(next_date) 
then sdate
else
date_trunc(month,next_date)
end fdate
 from data_cte d,
table(split_to_table(repeat(',',TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, sdate,edate)-1),',')) t
)
select
fdate Startdate,
next_date Enddate,
extract(year,Startdate) year,
extract(month,Startdate) month,
datediff(day,Startdate,Enddate)+1 no_of_days
 from cte_2
where (next_date = ldate
OR next_date = edate)
OR sdate = edate;
```

| STARTDATE | ENDDATE | YEAR | MONTH | NO_OF_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-14 | 2020-12-31 | 2020 | 12 | 18 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-14 | 2021 | 1 | 14 |
| 2020-12-13 | 2020-12-23 | 2020 | 12 | 11 |
| 2020-12-03 | 2020-12-31 | 2020 | 12 | 29 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 | 2021 | 1 | 31 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-03 | 2021 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: I think the only problem is handling the rows containing the same values for StartDate and EndDate. For example, ('XYZ','2020-12-22'::date,'2020-12-23'::date) returns 2 days (and it's correct based on Raghu's calculation), but ('XYZ','2020-12-23'::date,'2020-12-23'::date) returns no rows (instead of 1). Maybe it's not needed I don't know. Anyway, I still upvoted because split_to_table trick is really good!

Comment: Thanks @GokhanAtil for pointing that. My idea was mainly to get all dates. Then we can fetch what-ever dates as needed from them. I have edited solution for same dates scenario.

Comment: @Pankaj, this is perfect and it gave the correct solution to the requirement. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After you create out 'OUTPUT' table, you can insert records as:

INSERT INTO OUTPUT_TABLE
SELECT
ID,
StartDate,
EndDate,
YEAR(StartDate) as year,
MONTH(StartDate) as month,
DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate)
FROM INPUT_TABLE;

Comment: This answer is missing the calculations to determine how many months in between the start and end date, the end of month date, and the number of days inclusive for each month.  I would suggest creating a date dimension table which includes the year, start and end date for each month, number of days in that month.  The rest is derived from there comparing with the input.

Comment: Thanks For your response, But that doesnot give the expected output. 
We need No. of days for each month from the given input